# Within a VLC lua interface script, how does one invoke the httpd service?

Tags: scripting, lua, vlc

I've finally managed to figure out how to invoke the VLC executable so that it attempts to run an interface, and debug messages show up in the output when they're included within the script itself.

However, when I use the following code:

```
require "common"

function test_f()
    return 'this is a test'
end

h = vlc.httpd("localhost", 8090)
a = h:handler("/test",nil,nil,test_f,nil)
```

VLC blows up. It doesn't start an httpd on that port (or any other that I can determine). It claims permission is denied (and this on a port higher than 1024) and that it can't open the socket. [The documentation is rather lackluster](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt) and I was hoping someone could shed light on how to use this portion of the API properly (I was going to do a rest service interface, if I can figure this out).